# If the tangent at $(x_0,y_0)$ to the curve $x^3+y^3=a^3$ meets the curve again at $(x_1,x_1)$ then prove that $\frac{x_0}{x_1}+\frac{y_0}{y_1}=1$

Tags: calculus, curves, tangent-line

**Problem :** If the tangent at $(x_0,y_0)$ to the curve $x^3+y^3=a^3$ meets the curve again at $(x_1,x_1)$ then prove that $\frac{x_0}{x_1}+\frac{y_0}{y_1}=1$

We have tangent to the given curve at $(x_0,y_0)$ is
$$xx_0^2+yy_0^2=a^3$$.

Since it passes through $(x_1,y_1)$, so we get
$$x_1x_0^2+y_1y_0^2=a^3\tag{1}$$
Again, $(x_1,y_1)$ lies on the curve, so.

$$x_1^3+y_1^3=a^3\tag{2}$$.

How can I get the required result from above?

Comment: Is $$P(x_0,y_0)$$ situated on the curve?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner yes

Comment: refer to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/897196/tangent-to-curve-x3y3-a3-meets-it-again?rq=1

Comment: Don’t you mean $(x_1,y_1)$?

Answer (score 1):

$$x^3+y^3=a^3$$
$$3x^2+3y^2 y'=0$$
$$y'=-\frac{x^2}{y^2}$$

Thus tangent at $(x_0,y_0) $ can be written as

$$(y-y_0)=-\frac{x_0^2}{y_0^2}(x-x_0)$$
$$yy_0^2=-x_0^2x+x_o^3+y_0^3$$

The intersection of this line and curve $x^3+y^3=a^3$ is at the point $(x_1,y_1)$

thus $(x_1,y_1)$ satiesfies both the line and the curve

Thus we can write $$x_1^3+y_1^3=a^3$$

and $$y_1y_0^2=-x_0^2x_1+x_0^3+y_0^3$$
$$y_1y_0^2+x_0^2x_1=x_0^3+y_0^3$$

also $x_0^3+y_0^3=a^3$
Thus $$y_1y_0^2+x_0^2x_1=a^3$$
$$\frac{y_1}{y_0}y_0^3+\frac{x_1}{x_0}x_0^3=a^3$$

Comment: we have to show $\frac{x_0}{x_1}+\frac{y_0}{y_1}=1$

Comment: can't you from the last equations

Comment: also refer to the link in the comments

Comment: Your edit is basically what I've written.

Comment: Op was having trouble see that that' why

Comment: He can easily solve the last  equations to get to the result

Comment: According to you $x_0/x_1=y_0/y_1=\pm 1\implies x_0/x_1+y_0/y_1=2$ or $-2$ @James

Comment: I think only 2 but solve the last equations and get the result

Answer (score 0):

We have $$y=(a^3-x^3)^{1/3}\implies y'=-\frac{x^2}{y^2}$$ so the tangent line is $$y-y_0=-\frac{x_0^2}{y_0^2}(x-x_0)\implies y_0^2y=-x_0^2x+a^3$$ Now at $(x_1,y_1)$, we get $$x_0^2x_1+y_0^2y_1=a^3\implies\left(\frac{x_0}{x_1}\right)^2x_1^3+\left(\frac{y_0}{y_1}\right)^2y_1^3=a^3$$ from which the result follows.

Comment: We have to show $\frac{x_0}{x_1}+\frac{y_0}{y_1}=1$

Comment: We have that $(x_0/x_1)^2=(y_0/y_1)^2=1$ from the equation $x^3+y^3=a^3$! The question is wrong.#

Comment: According to you $x_0/x_1=y_0/y_1=\pm 1\implies x_0/x_1+y_0/y_1=2$ or $-2$ @TheSimplifire

Comment: Yes, and so the Q is wrong.